# Dynamic routes in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

How to write custom routes in codeigniter?

```
$route['codeigniter/getAllCategories'] = "codeigniter/category_controller/getAllCategories";
$route['default_controller'] = "admin";
$route['404_override'] = '';
http://localhost/codeigniter/category_controller/getAllCategories
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'category_controller/$1/$2';
```

Comment: I've fixed your indentation. Please pay attention to correctly using markdown so your post is readable. However, the question is still not clear. Maybe you should edit it and add some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are doing , you can do the concept of slug in codeigniter to create dynamic routes. Check this link.
http://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter